# Access userid into the directive from html

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="user in children">

 <a ng-click="swapUser(user.user_id);"></a>

    <div ng-model="player.name" currentuser="user.user_id" inline-edit="parentUser.name" on-save="log('SAVE', value)" on-cancel="log('CANCEL', value)"></div>
</div>
```

Directive :

```
return {
    scope: {
      model: '=inlineEdit',
      handleSave: '&onSave',
      currentuser: '=',
      handleCancel: '&onCancel'
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var currentuser = attr.currentuser;
    console.log("Userid", attr.currentuser);
    //Here I want to set the user_id so that i can update respective users
    scope.save = function() {
        var objInput = {};
        objInput[field] = scope.model;

        user.updateConfirmUser(objInput, currentuser)
        .success(function () {
          console.log("Saved");
        });
     }
```

Controller :

```
$scope.children = [
       {
            "name" : "Amy",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "2",
            "user_id" : "1"
        },{

            "name" : "Rock",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "2",
            "user_id" : "2"
        },{
            "name" : "Jimmy",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "3",
            "user_id" : "3"
        },{
            "name" : "Michael",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "3",
            "user_id" : "4"
        }

];
```

How can i access the currentuser into my directive from html i setup current user to attr and trying to access into directive it says undefined user_id. Please take a look above code and suggest thanks

Comment: `console.log("Userid", attr.currentuser);` should be `console.log("Userid", scope.currentuser);`

Comment: That's true but does not solve my issue What i want when swapUser(user.user_id) get clicked i could able to send this id to my directive how it is possible

Comment: [here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgjsdvec/)

Comment: Here is my updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tgjsdvec/1/

Comment: it should return console.log("C", currentuser); in directive

Comment: where is your swapUser() function . Can you show html code for it ?

Comment: Updated code vertika and see fiddle if you have any confusion

Comment: I should be `currentuser="user.user_id"` [here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pxh6oc7/1/)

Comment: that is okay but attribute of directive can be change dynamically what would be the best way to use in directive

Answer (score 0):

You are binding currentuser with value of "user.user_id" so only the user_id will be passed.

Try to pass the entire object: `currentuser="user"`